# Сохранить измененную css-ом картинку

Tags: css, изображения

#### Описание

Есть картинка:

[image]

В ходе разработки поставил её как задний фон и задал стили...

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}
```

... и получилось это:

[image]

В основном её изменила стиль `baackground-blend-mode: color-dodge` и теперь такой оттенок не могу получить ни в одном фоторедакторе. Понравилась, хочу скачать.

#### Вопрос

Как можно скачать измененную css-ом картинку?

---

Делать скриншот не советуйте. :)
Это как последний вариант есть в уме, хотя и качество сильно упадет.

#### Дополнение

Вот [ссылка](https://eccs0103.github.io/) на страницу, вдруг пригодится. Страница моя и там на данный момент эта картинка стоит, но на будущее не могу сказать останется или нет.

Comment: Нууу, наверное перегнать картинку [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), а потом уже скачивать.

Comment: В photoshop изображения/коррекция/кривые в вкладке стиль Darker(RGB) тянешь точку немного вниз, через одну клетку разметки ставишь вторую точку, тянешь её немного вверх. Adobe Photoshop версия: 10.0

Comment: @De.Minov, она так же [копирует без стилей](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz6pL.jpg)

Comment: @Rudi так как ваш способ примерно выдает результат, я немного подумал о том что вы советовали и похожим способом решил проблему. Сейчас опишу.

Comment: Я бы еще с уровнями поигрался после кривых. И возможно слой с фильтром наложил, затем настройка прозрачности и смешения.. У меня картинка на страничке так не отображается, css пощелкал изменений цвета не было. Chrome Версия 88.0.4324.182

Comment: @Rudi у вас светлая тема? Для светлой темы там баг есть. Сегодня заметил.

Comment: Да, стандартный..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Photoshop если, создаете слой с фигурой, заполняете цветом `rgb(25, 25, 25);`.
Выше слой c изображением, высатвляете ему режим наложения "Осветление основы" (тот самый "Color Dodge") – получаете ровно такой же результат, как и в браузере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]